# WPF Tooltip "opened" event binding to viewmodel is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm, tooltip

I spend a lot of time to understand why it is not working, it just MUST work but it doesn't...

Let's imagine I have ItemsControl binded to ObservableCollection. Inside ItemsControl.ItemTemplate there are StackPanel with buttons, textblocks etc.
I want to bind ToolTip Opened event attached to StackPanel to my Command, and I need instance of model also.

```
<StackPanel.ToolTip>
  <ToolTip>
    <TextBlock Text="Example text"></TextBlock>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="Opened">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.TooltipOpenCommand, ElementName=MapsControl}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
      </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
  </ToolTip>
</StackPanel.ToolTip>
```

My C# code is:

```
public ICommand TooltipOpenCommand => new RelayCommand(ToolTipOpen);

public void ToolTipOpen(object obj)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Test message");
}
```

(`RelayCommand` is just default Command example from internet with execute and `CanExecute`)

So, when I hover mouse on `StackPanel`, tooltip with "Example text" is appears but command is not executed, I can't ever understand why, what am I doing wrong?

By the way, to prove that it MUST work, check this code(it attached just to the same StackPanel in example above, but not to tooltip). AND THIS CODE IS WORKING!!! But the code above isn't...

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.TooltipOpenCommand, ElementName=MapsControl}"
                           CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
  </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: have you tried using  `{Binding}` ? what type is your argument in this case?

Comment: yes, it's actually CommandParameter = "{Bindng}" in my code. Changed it here now, error with tooltip still presents ;(